# Получить имя файла в Tkinter и вывести его имя

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

программа должна создавать окно, в нем по центру кнопка, при нажатии на нее открывается окно выбора файла, и после выбора название файла должно быть написано внизу под кнопкой. ни как не могу сделат ьпоследнюю часть, название выводит только в консоли, попытка вывести `filename` из функции приводит к ошибке.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter.constants import CENTER
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename

def UploadAction(event=None):
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    print('Selected:', filename)

root= tk.Tk()

canvas1 = tk.Canvas(root, width = 300, height = 300)
canvas1.pack()
    
button1 = tk.Button(text='Click Me',command=UploadAction, bg='brown',fg='white')
canvas1.create_window(150, 150, window=button1)
button1.place (relx = 0.5, rely = 0.5, anchor=CENTER)
canvas1.create_text(relx = 0.5, rely = 0.7, anchor=CENTER, text= filename, fill="black", font=('Helvetica 15 bold'))

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Вот вместо `print('Selected:', filename)` (или ниже него в той же функции) делаете отображение имени файла где вам нужно. Если возникает ошибка, укажите код, который к ней приводит, и текст самой ошибки в вопросе.

Answer (score 0):

Вы сейчас выводите результат в консоль, потому что `print()` выводит в консоль.
Чтобы вывести результат под кнопкой, вам нужна область под кнопкой, в которую вы будете это делать (посмотрите какие есть варианты в tkinter'е и выберите наиболее подходящий).

Вот пример, но с выводом результата в `button1` из вашего кода:

```
def UploadAction(event=None):
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    button1['text'] = f'Selected: {filename}'


if name == '__main__':
    root= tk.Tk()

    canvas1 = tk.Canvas(root, width = 300, height = 300)
    canvas1.pack()
    
    button1 = tk.Button(text='Click Me',command=UploadAction, bg='brown',fg='white')
    canvas1.create_window(150, 150, window=button1)
    button1.place (relx = 0.5, rely = 0.5, anchor=CENTER)
    canvas1.create_text(relx = 0.5, rely = 0.7, anchor=CENTER, text= filename, 
    fill="black", font=('Helvetica 15 bold'))

    root.mainloop()
```